# How to use multiple functions to manipulate a text

Tags: php, string

I've just got started with computer programming and I bumped in this tough test for a beginner.

I want to manipulate this text:
`Blurry TV-film around chique skybox`

to

`TV--film-around-chique-skybox`

with the PHP functions; `str_replace()`, `trim()`, `ucwords()` and `strstr()`.
If I try it I get a error or the sentence gets doubled up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far? Basically, with the given functions, you can get in the final result you're expecting.

Comment: How were you using those functions?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague as I assume that the question you were given is more complex than it appears from your question.

This is how you can solve your problem if it has to do with the same word, separators every time.

```php
$myString = "Blurry TV-film around chique skybox";

function parseString(string $aString) {
    //here you can apply as many rules as you'd like
    // you can also apply this outside of a function ofcourse
    $newString = str_replace("Blurry ","",$aString);
    $newString = str_replace("-","--",$newString);
    $newString = str_replace(" ","-",$newString);
    echo $newString;
    return $newString;
}

$testString = "Blurry TV-film around chique skybox";
parseString($testString);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f343f15e5373c84b66ca8c2fa93681a797f5ac75

If the use case that you're trying to solve is more dynamics and requires handling random words and separators, let me know.